# Can't remove noindex meta tag from head

Tags: noindex

Bit of a strange one.  One of my clients site is showing
`<meta name='robots' content='noindex,follow' />` in the head.  The Search Engine Visibility checkbox is unchecked.

I've tried activating 2019 theme and deactivating all plugins and still the tag shows.

Never encountered this before.  Any ideas?

Comment: In https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/333807/30597 someone had the same problem. Turned out former dev hacked core header template.

Comment: I replaced all the core files with fresh updated version.  Didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the `blog_public` option in the options table is set to `1`. If that looks right, make sure nothing is adding that tag via the `wp_head` action. Also make sure this isn't being set by any plugins. This is common for SEO plugins.

Comment: I checked blog_public in the options table already.  I also activated default 2019 theme and disabled all plugins and it still doesn't get rid of the noindex tag.

Comment: If that's the case, something else is going on. Does your host have any mu plugins or `wp-config.php` changes?

Answer (score 0):

To switch from noindex to index from inside a template:

```
    <?php 
        global $wp_filter;
        foreach($wp_filter['wpseo_robots_array']->callbacks[10] as $k => $v){
            $robots = $v['function'];
        }
        remove_filter( 'wpseo_robots_array', $robots );
    ?>
```

see:
https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/blob/f6719d2e5d6eb173ab6a9ca63093b422582d66be/src/integrations/front-end/indexing-controls.php#L53

Or, much easier:

```
update_option('blog_public', 1);
```